# jhipster - Angular HttpClient calls with option {observe: 'response'}

Tags: angular, http, jhipster

JHipster generated Angular Services uses an option `{observe: 'response'}`
for httpClient calls e.g.

```
this.httpClient.get<IEntity>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })...
```

Is there any special reason to do this? Why do they want to receive the full response. (maybe some generic handling of headers or so...)

TIA

Answer (score 2):

By default the HttpClient returns the body of the response. You can pass-in an object with an `observe` key set to a value of `‘response’` to get the full response. This can be useful to inspect for certain headers, for e.g:

```
getData() {
  this.http.get<Post>(this.url, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
    this.powered = res.headers.get('X-Powered-By');
    this.postTitle = res.body.title;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I am aware of this. The question was if JHipster do anything with this information in a generic way. Because of otherwise it would not make sense to me to handle the request in this manner...